# How to achieve a grainy, shiny, black surface?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I am trying to achieve the following surface:
 - grainy
 - shiny
 - black tint

Pretty much like a hard mouse pad surface:

[image]

So I've started with 50% of uniform noise that looks promising:

[image]

But then,

- inverting colors obviously has no effect as it's gray
- tried to play with levels to darken it but then that shiny aspect is lost

**Question:**

How can I mimic a black, grainy and shiny surface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For good resolution start with large enough pixel resolution, for.ex 2000 x 2000

- fill a layer with 50% grey
- add 100% monochromatic noise
- add 1...2 px gaussian blur to get larger smooth details

[image]

You need narrow grooves between glosses. Create them by turning dark and bright areas white and a narrow mid grey range to black:

[image]

Create microscopic 3D light effect to the grooves by inserting 1px 100% embossing, the light direction pointer is here downwards:

[image]

Flat areas became 50% grey, the grooves have adjacent black and white strokes:

[image]

Use this to texturize the surface which has only the large scale light effect, use blending mode Hard light. Try different opacities. Here the bottom layer is a linear gradient white to black and the texture has its maximum effect; the opacity is 100%:

[image]

With some perspective this can be good enough although it isn't made as 3D.

[image]

ADD: The dark areas of the large scale surface light layer can look too full of noise with fully bright texture. To reduce the texture brightness in dark areas insert a curves layer which has the negative of the large scale light in the layer mask, the "next layer only"-switch ON and a curve which reduces the contrast by darkening:

[image]

Comment: I'll be honest, before your edit today "that's not even close" was all I thought. But what a great edit!  +1

Answer (score 0):

I went with this way of thinking:

- shiny so a reflection must be present, reflection from a source of light. This can be imittated by overlaying gradient (1 layer).
- underlying layer. The texture the mouspad have can be best, IMHO, described as "leathery". I call it brainy as it looks like brain to me, multiple hills connected with clearly visible valleys and almost vertical sides (so small amout of grey).

So step one-

1. As User287001 - greaty 50% gray layer add noise. I used 87%, uniform distribution monochromatic, [image: picture 1]
2. Add Median, set to 1 pixel, repeated until you are content. I prefer to apply 1 pixel median 3 times rather than 3 pixels once. It give more organic feeling. [image: picture 2]
3. Change brightness/contrast. I put brightness almost to -100 and upped the contrast. This is a trick I learned from experience. I'm looking for "asphalt" black as then I can add extra color with overlay or by layer style. [image]
4. Added final gradient. Using it on additional layer give me possibility to move it around and match better the final scene[image].

The rest is just adding additional blur to whole scene to give similar feel like in the source (that add to the perspective "realness")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple way out...

1. once you have chosen the preferred gradient and blend mode
2. convert to smart object and go to Top bar Menu ->Fliter ->Noise -> Add Noise.
3. adjust till you are satisfied.

My Result

[image]